# How to check where a user opened a url in PHP without $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Tags: php

I'm trying to check whether the user has moved from a specific site.
But this site doesn't send `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, so I can't use it.

Maybe some one knows, how to realise this:

1) User navigates to my site from example.com (no `HTTP_REFERER`)

2) When user loads my page, I need to check where this user is from.

Can this be done without the `HTTP_REFERER` header?

Comment: Don't think you can.  And `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is determined by the client and is always suspect.

Comment: If you have a good relationship with the referring site, you might ask them to add some sort of tag to the links they construct pointing to you. For example, http://yoursite.example.org/resource?source=example.com .  Your site can safely ignore the variable in the GET, but it will show up in your logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer IT.

I will use API on referring site.

Thanks!